# What am I doing wrong when invoking AWS API GetSuppressedDestination

Tags: amazon-web-services, sesv2

I want to retrieve a details of suppressed email from the AWS SES service. For this I am making a request to the Amazon WS API using the GetSuppressedDestination API. And I'm signing the requests with "Signature Version 4". I don't use the AWS SDK due to incompatibility with the production environment.
The problem is that I do not receive data, but a response that I do not understand. Here is the answer:
`"{"message":"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details."}"`

My code is Here

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
$accessKey = "MyKey";
$secretKey = "MySecrete";
$region = 'us-east-1';

$hostApi = "email.$region.amazonaws.com";
$verbo = "GET";
$path = "/v2/email/suppression/addresses";
$email =  rawurlencode('dfwfwf@de.com');
$path = $path . '/' . $email ;


$parameters = Array();
// setParameter('Action', 'ListSuppressedDestinations');
// setParameter('Version', '2019-09-27');
// setParameter('EndDate', date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day')));
// setParameter('pageSize', 10);
// setParameter('Reason', 'BOUNCE');
// setParameter('StartDate', date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-60 days')));
//setParameter('EmailAddress', 'dfwfwf@de.com');

ksort($parameters);
$query = http_build_query($parameters, '', '&', PHP_QUERY_RFC1738);
$resulset = requestCurl($hostApi, $parameters, 'GET');
var_dump($resulset);

function requestCurl($hostApi, $parameters = array(), $method = 'GET') {

    global $hostApi;
    global $path;
    
    $url = 'https://'.$hostApi.'/'.$path;
    
    ksort($parameters);
    $query = http_build_query($parameters, '', '&', PHP_QUERY_RFC1738);
    $headers = getHeaders($query);

    /*
        * Opciones de CURL
    */
    $curlOption = array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => $method,
            CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT=>true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_URL => $url . '?' . $query,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers
    );


    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, $curlOption);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
            return $err;
    }

    return $response;
}


function setParameter($key, $value, $replace = true) {
    global $parameters;
    
    if(!$replace && isset($this->parameters[$key])) {
        $temp = (array)($this->parameters[$key]);
        $temp[] = $value;
        $parameters[$key] = $temp;
    } else {
        $parameters[$key] = $value;
    }

}

function getHeaders($query) {
    global $hostApi;

    $headers = array();

    $date = (new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('UTC')))->format('Ymd\THis\Z');
    $headers[] = 'X-Amz-Date: ' . $date;
    $headers[] = 'Host: ' . $hostApi;
    $headers[] = 'Authorization: ' . getAuthHeaderV4($date, $query);

    return $headers;
}


function getAuthHeaderV4($amz_datetime, $query) {
    global $hostApi;
    global $verbo;
    global $secretKey;
    global $accessKey;
    global $hostApi;
    global $path;
    
    $amz_date = substr($amz_datetime, 0, 8);
    $algo = 'sha256';
    $aws_algo = 'AWS4-HMAC-' . strtoupper($algo);

    $host_parts = explode('.', $hostApi );
    $service = $host_parts[0];
    $service = "ses";
    $region = 'us-east-1';

    $canonical_uri = 'https://'.$hostApi.'/'.$path.'/';
    if($verbo === 'POST') {
        $canonical_querystring = '';
        $payload_data = $query;
    } else {
        $canonical_querystring = $query;
        $payload_data = '';
    }
    
    // ************* TASK 1: CREATE A CANONICAL REQUEST *************
    $canonical_headers_list = [
        'host:' . $hostApi,
        'x-amz-date:' . $amz_datetime
    ];

    $canonical_headers = implode("\n", $canonical_headers_list) . "\n";
    
    $signed_headers = 'host;x-amz-date';
    $payload_hash = hash($algo, $payload_data, false);

    $canonical_request = implode("\n", array(
        $verbo,
        $path,
        $canonical_querystring,
        $canonical_headers,
        $signed_headers,
        $payload_hash
    ));


    // ************* TASK 2: CREATE THE STRING TO SIGN*************
    $credential_scope = $amz_date. '/' . $region . '/' . $service . '/' . 'aws4_request';

    $string_to_sign = implode("\n", array(
        $aws_algo,
        $amz_datetime,
        $credential_scope,
        hash($algo, $canonical_request, false)
    ));

    // ************* TASK 3: CALCULATE THE SIGNATURE *************
    // Create the signing key using the function defined above.
    $signing_key = getSigningKey($secretKey, $amz_date, $region, $service, $algo);

    // Sign the string_to_sign using the signing_key
    $signature = hash_hmac($algo, $string_to_sign, $signing_key, false);

    // ************* TASK 4: ADD SIGNING INFORMATION TO THE REQUEST *************

    
    return $aws_algo . ' ' . implode(', ', array(
        'Credential=' . $accessKey . '/' . $credential_scope,
        'SignedHeaders=' . $signed_headers ,
        'Signature=' . $signature
    ));
}

function getSigningKey($key, $dateStamp, $regionName, $serviceName, $algo) {
    $kDate = hash_hmac($algo, $dateStamp, 'AWS4' . $key, true);
    $kRegion = hash_hmac($algo, $regionName, $kDate, true);
    $kService = hash_hmac($algo, $serviceName, $kRegion, true);

    return hash_hmac($algo,'aws4_request', $kService, true);
}
```

Comment: This code is work for /v2/email/suppression/addresses but not work for /v2/email/suppression/addresses/{$email}